# Armazenar dados de um for em um dataframe

Tags: r, for

Tenho códigos de aeroportos e necessitava armazenar o link de acesso dos dados desses aeroportos em um `DF`, tentei fazer através de um `for`, mas está retornando erro.

Código que utilizei:

```
aeroportos <- c("bsb",
                "cgh",
                "gru",
                "vcp",
                "sdu",
                "gig",
                "poa", 
                "cwb",
                "cnf", 
                "bel",
                "ssa",
                "rec", 
                "for",
                "slz",
                "cgr")

links <- data.frame(aeroporto = aeroportos, link = NA)

for(i in aeroportos) {
  
  for(j in 1:aeroportos) {
    
    link[j,2] <- paste0("https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/", i,"/statistics"))  
    
  }
}
```

Está retornando o seguinte erro:

> Erro: '}' inesperado in "}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alguns erros são:

Olha a linha `link[j,2]` tem dois `))` remova 1 deles...

vc criou um dataframe chamado `links` mas depois está tentando alimentar o `link`(sem o "s"),  ou seja existe bastante erros de sintaxe...

Aparentemente você está querendo alimentar o dataframe `links` com a URL do aeroporto certo? se for isso não precisa criar dois `fors`, crie uma variável auxiliar que incremente a cada iteração um `j` por exemplo, o código funcional ficaria assim:

```
aeroportos <- c("bsb",
                "cgh",
                "gru",
                "vcp",
                "sdu",
                "gig",
                "poa", 
                "cwb",
                "cnf", 
                "bel",
                "ssa",
                "rec", 
                "for",
                "slz",
                "cgr")

links <- data.frame(aeroporto = aeroportos, link = NA)

j=1;

for(i in aeroportos) {
  
 links[j,2] <- paste0("https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/", i,"/statistics") 

 j=j+1;
    
 
}

print(links)
```

resultado do `print(links)`:

```
   aeroporto                                                       link
1        bsb https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bsb/statistics
2        cgh https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/cgh/statistics
3        gru https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/gru/statistics
4        vcp https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/vcp/statistics
5        sdu https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/sdu/statistics
6        gig https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/gig/statistics
7        poa https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/poa/statistics
8        cwb https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/cwb/statistics
9        cnf https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/cnf/statistics
10       bel https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bel/statistics
11       ssa https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/ssa/statistics
12       rec https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/rec/statistics
13       for https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/for/statistics
14       slz https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/slz/statistics
15       cgr https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/cgr/statistics
```

Comment: Obrigado! Não tinha notado esse erro do nome do objeto! Funcionou perfeitamente.